# Where do I report issues with official archive mirrors?

Tags: mirrors

apt-get has been failing to retrieve two files from German archive mirror de.archive.ubuntu.com for some days:

```
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/multiverse amd64 Packages
[...]
Err http://de.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/universe i386 Packages
  406  Not Acceptable [IP: 141.30.13.20 80]
Err http://de.archive.ubuntu.com saucy/multiverse i386 Packages
  406  Not Acceptable [IP: 141.30.13.20 80]
[...]
W: Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/universe/binary-i386/Packages  406  Not Acceptable [IP: 141.30.13.20 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  406  Not Acceptable [IP: 141.30.13.20 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Whom should I report this issue to?

Comment: Actually, no!
The previous answer is 100% correct in principle, but only in principle.
Here it is a double-bug of Ubuntu, handling partial files.
cd /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ will show partial files, sudo rm *
(be very careful!! that you're in the right place!!)
will clean those out. And miraculously, another sudo apt-get update will go through. Have fun!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you should report it. Just send a mail to mirrors@ubuntu.com with the time, ip, and log of the problem that you were facing. Or drop by the irc channel at irc://irc.freenode.net/ubuntu-mirrors

You can also report a ticket visiting https://rt.ubuntu.com or sending a mail to rt@ubuntu.com.

<sub>Thanks to [Benjamin Drung](https://askubuntu.com/users/143232/benjamin-drung) (OP) and [Jorge Castro](https://askubuntu.com/users/235/jorge-castro) for pointing this out.</sub>

From the [w3c page](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html):

> ### 406 Not Acceptable
>
> The resource identified by the request is only capable of generating response entities which have content characteristics not acceptable according to the accept headers sent in the request.
>
> Unless it was a HEAD request, the response SHOULD include an entity containing a list of available entity characteristics and location(s) from which the user or user agent can choose the one most appropriate. The entity format is specified by the media type given in the Content-Type header field. Depending upon the format and the capabilities of the user agent, selection of the most appropriate choice MAY be performed automatically. However, this specification does not define any standard for such automatic selection.
>
> ```
>  Note: HTTP/1.1 servers are allowed to return responses which are
>   not acceptable according to the accept headers sent in the
>   request. In some cases, this may even be preferable to sending a
>   406 response. User agents are encouraged to inspect the headers of
>   an incoming response to determine if it is acceptable.
> ```
>
> If the response could be unacceptable, a user agent SHOULD temporarily stop receipt of more data and query the user for a decision on further actions.

Comment: Yes, I want to report this issue. My question is: Where should I report it? Who has the power to fix it?

Comment: @BenjaminDrung I'm not 100% sure but I think a ticket to rt@ubuntu.com might help.

Comment: @BenjaminDrung There's this as well: https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-archive

Comment: The [ubuntu-archive mailing list](https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-archive) is the mailing list for the [~ubuntu-archive Launchpad team](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-archive). This is unrelated to the maintenance of the archive mirrors.

Comment: I reported the issue via a ticket on [rt.ubuntu.com](https://rt.ubuntu.com/) in the Mirrors section two days ago. The issue disappeared yesterday.

Comment: Will add your ( @BenjaminDrung ) solution to my answer.